# Amazon Associates - Can't find Associate Tag, API and Secret Key

Tags: php, amazon-ecs, amazon-selling-partner-api

How do I find the necessary keys for this code to work?

```
<?php
/**
 * For a running Search Demo see: http://amazonecs.pixel-web.org
 */

if ("cli" !== PHP_SAPI)
{
    echo "<pre>";
}




defined('AWS_API_KEY') or define('AWS_API_KEY', '...');
defined('AWS_API_SECRET_KEY') or define('AWS_API_SECRET_KEY', '...');
defined('AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG') or define('AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG', '...');

// require '../lib/AmazonECS.class.php';
require_once ( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../classes/buyamerica/AmazonECS.class.php');


try
{
    $amazonEcs = new AmazonECS(AWS_API_KEY, AWS_API_SECRET_KEY, 'com', AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG);

    // for the new version of the wsdl its required to provide a associate Tag
    // @see https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/api-changes.html?ie=UTF8&pf_rd_t=501&ref_=amb_link_83957571_2&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=&pf_rd_s=assoc-center-1&pf_rd_r=&pf_rd_i=assoc-api-detail-2-v2
    // you can set it with the setter function or as the fourth paramameter of ther constructor above
    $amazonEcs->associateTag(AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG);

    // First of all you have to set an another ResponseGroup. If not the request would not be successful
    // Possible Responsegroups: BrowseNodeInfo,MostGifted,NewReleases,MostWishedFor,TopSellers
    $amazonEcs->responseGroup('BrowseNodeInfo');
    // $asin = "B00625Q56U";
    $asin = $_REQUEST["asin"];
    $res = $amazonEcs->responseGroup('Large')->lookup($asin);

    var_dump($res->Items->Item);

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

if ("cli" !== PHP_SAPI)
{
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To find your Associate Tag you simply log into your Affiliate Account. On the left you will find a box where it says "Tracking ID", this is what you need. Or simply follow this link: https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/network/your-account/manage-tracking-ids.html

In the AWS management console navigate to 'Security Credentials' under the dropdown over your name (https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential). Under 'Access Keys' you can see your root access keys (the ones assigned to your root user created when you signed up with Product Advertising API). 
delete one, then generate a new one. It will show you the proper AWS key and Secret Key. These paired with the proper Associate Tag should get you access to the API.

Comment: So the Tracking ID is the Associate Tag?